# label control does not update when I toggle light and dark mode

Tags: .net, maui, c#-7.0

all other controls in my app are responsive to the app theme change caused by toggling appearance. Label control does not.

If I restart the application the text is the correct color, but when I try it while the app is running, no dice.

I would like to see the color of the text in the label change.

I am using a resource dictionary with the following code:

```
    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource TextColor},
            Dark={StaticResource DarkTextColor}}" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    </Style>
```

Comment: Can you check this bug, if its relevant https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6183

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code on my side both windows11 and Android platform. It worked well when I change the light and dark mode.

Here is the code:

```
 <ContentPage.Resources>
        <!-- Light colors -->
        <Color x:Key="LightSecondaryColor">Black</Color>

        <!-- Dark colors -->
        <Color x:Key="DarkSecondaryColor">Teal</Color>


        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightSecondaryColor},
            Dark={StaticResource DarkSecondaryColor}}" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
```